# python uses 100% of single CPU (Google Compute Engine) - RealESRGAN

Tags: python, google-cloud-vm

I have the following setup:

- Google Compute Engine VM with Nvidia Tesla T4 , 4CPU 16GB RAM
- Conda environment where I am running the `inference_realesrgan.py` cloned from https://github.com/xinntao/Real-ESRGAN
- Everything works as expected - the upscaling process is fine, but slow, the bottleneck is probably not the NVidia GPU, but the python process which uses only a single thread - probably for reading/converting/handling images by opencv? (see the attached image)
- My goal: utilize all 4 CPUs during the upscale process
- my initial command: `conda activate base && python ~/Real-ESRGAN/inference_realesrgan.py -i ~/in -o ~/out -dn 1 -t 660 -g 0  --model_path  ~/my_model.pth`

The screenshot from Google Cloud VM - htop:
[image]

Any hint/help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) runs CPU tasks in a single thread. But the multiprocessing module might help, if there are enough images to warrant parallelizing.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def upscale_image(image_path):
    # Your upscaling code here
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_paths = [...]  # List of input images
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(upscale_image, image_paths)
```

Comment: The upscaling itself cannot be paralellizd, as the GPU usage hits the 20GB limit,  the whole upscaling will crash if I will run it on more than one thread. However, I guess the process itself can run quicker if I will be able to eliminate that single CPU bottleneck.